# column validation across survey questions

Tags: column, validation, survey

I want to validate responses to a question in a survey using information from a previous question and I just can't get the survey to take the validation formula.

Basically:

Q1 = How many hours do you work
Q2 = How many of these hours are in meetings

For Q2 I have tried column validation of "<[How many hours do you work]" on the basis that [How many hours do you work] is the column name for Q1 - however all I get is a SharePoint error saying the formula is broken. Almost feels like you can't validate across questions.

I do need it a bit more complicated, validating that the sum of a number of questions (ie Q2 + Q3 + Q4) equals Q1.

Any help greatly appreciated.